# how to run gcr.io/google-containers/echoserver:1.8 image?

Tags: docker

i would like to run the docker image gcr.io/google-containers/echoserver:1.8. i tried this command `docker run -d gcr.io/google-containers/echoserver:1.8 -p 8081:80` but it seems not to work. there is the error message:

[image]

and when i insert the `docker ps` command, no process is running. i don't know if parameters are placed badly or it is not the right command to run this image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the strings after the image name is considered as a command to run in the container:

you may use:

```
docker run -d  -p 8081:80 gcr.io/google-containers/echoserver:1.8
```

then the container will run the Entrypoint/CMD wich is configured in the image